# Workaround for generics with static methods

Tags: c#, generics

I'm implementing a custom Assert class similar to [NUnit's Assert](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/blob/be57a0da7285548ddbeefe6af4fdb4e33af5d169/src/NUnitFramework/framework/Assert.cs).

We have Sonar turned on with StyleCop rules and it complains that I should always use generics instead of `object`. If I change my class to a generic one, then I fall into the rule that generic classes cannot have static methods.

For example, consider this code (a very simplified version of my current method):

```
public class Assert
{
    public static void PropertyHasValue(object obj, string propertyName, object expectedValue)
    {
        var value = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(obj, null);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, value);
    }
}
```

Having instance methods in an Assert class wouldn't make any sense in my opnion. A generic method would force me to do something like this (untested) when wanting to use TestCases:

```
[TestCase("someProperty", 10)]
[TestCase("anotherProperty", "someString")]
public void TestMethod(string propertyName, object expectedValue)
{
    Assert.PropertyHasValue<object>(myObj, propertyName, expectedValue);
}
```

How could I best refactor this class to comply with both of these rules?

Comment: Can you exemplify with code? Have you considered extension methods?

Comment: Class doesn't have to be generic. Make the method generic instead.

Answer (score 4):

I would ask a different question: why would you ever need method like this?

Isn't `Assert.PropertyHasValue(foo, "bar", true)` the same as `Assert.AreEqual(foo.bar, true)`?

It's:

- cleaner
- no chance to make a typo in property name
- you get compile time safety

If you really need to do that, you'd probably want to use `Func<U, T>` instead of `string` to specify your properties:

```
public static class Assert
{
    public static void PropertyHasValue<T,U>(T obj, Func<T, U> propertyGetter, U expectedValue)
    {
        var value = propertyGetter(obj);
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedValue, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why oh why didn't I take the blue pill?